# restrictions on the fundamental group of a knot complement?

Tags: knot-theory

Are there any restrictions on $\pi_1(S^3\backslash K)$ for a (tame) knot $K$ besides having $\pi_1^{\text{ab}}(S^3\backslash K)=\mathbb{Z}$?

---

So we have 1) finite presentation, 2) $H_1=\mathbb{Z}$, 3) $H_2=0$, and I saw somewhere 4) the knot group must be the normal closure of a single element.

Apparently this characterizes knot groups in dimensions $n\geq5$ (i.e. $\pi_1(S^n\backslash S^{n-2})$), but fails to do so in lower dimensions.  Basically I just wanted to know if there is simple characterization of knot groups (not "it has a presentation that looks like a wirtinger presentation")

Comment: Well, it has to be finitely presented, for instance.

Comment: Aren't there restrictions that come just from it being the fundamental group of a 3-manifold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Maybe it shouldn't be an answer, as I won't say anything no one said before.)

A knot group is indeed a f.p. (obvious) group whose H1 is Z and H2 is 0 (by Alexander's duality). Moreover, as the meridian normally generates the group (that's a clear consequence of the Wirtinger's presentation), its weight is one. (The weight is the minimal number of "normal" generators. As far as I know, it's still a very mysterious group invariant.)

One of the early successes of surgery theory was to prove that these properties characterize knot groups of high dimension. (Michel Kervaire, *Les nœuds de dimension supérieure* (1965), [available here](http://archive.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1965__93__225_0.pdf).)

But, as always, the dimension three is more restrictive. For example, a knot exterior is a [Haken manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haken_manifold) so Waldhausen's work imply a lot of restrictions. For a start, the word problem for this knot has to be solvable.

I'm sure that all the things we know about geometric decomposition and 3-manifold groups give various restrictions (for example, Stallings's fibration theorem imply that if you have an epimorphism from a knot group to a f.g. group whose kernel if f.g., then it comes from a fibration on the circle; in particular, the kernel is a surface group and the image is Z).

But I think that no definitive answer is known. Globally, 3-manifold groups are still mysterious (we still don't know if they are linear!) and they are just very particular quotients of link groups so I think our knowledge of them is still limited.

Comment: In fact, groups with weight one are precisely quotients of knot groups.

Answer (score 8):

Famously, knot groups are torsion free.  One proof of this uses the fact that $S^3 - K$ is a $K(\pi, 1)$.

Another nice fact - knots have Seifert surfaces and so knot groups contain free groups.

Another one - knot complements have Heegaard splittings.  It follows that any knot group has a presentation with one more generator than relation.

I think that combining Waldhausen's work with Gordon-Luecke should prove that the knot group (possibly equipped with a $Z^2$ "peripheral" subgroup) determines the knot in $S^3$.

Neuwirth wrote a book entitled "Knot groups", published in 1965. There is lots more to know since then!

Answer (score 1):

If $\pi$ is a knot group, in addition to $H_1(\pi)=\mathbb Z$, you also have $H_2(\pi)=0$. This is because $H_2(S^3\setminus K)=0$, and $K(\pi,1)=(S^3\setminus K)$ union  cells of dimension $\geq 3$. So $H_2(S^3\setminus K)$ surjects onto $H_2(K(\pi,1))=H_2(\pi)$.